# Time complexity of specific variant of Turing Machine

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Assume a variant of a one-tape deterministic Turing Machine that reads and writes on the portion of the tape that the input $w$ appears (like linear bounded automata).
My question is, how we could bound the time complexity for membership in this type of Turing machine?

I think the time complexity could be the worst as exponential, the reason is if we consider $|w|=n$ and $|\Sigma |=k$ we might have $k^n$ configurations. Consequently, the worst case could be exponential according to $w$. Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the machine is a decider, meaning halts on its input $w$, then it does not repeat a configuration in its run on $w$. Hence, the number of configurations that the machine can be in bounds its running time from above. The number of configurations is at most $|Q| \cdot |\Sigma|^n \cdot n = 2^{log(|Q|\cdot |\Sigma|^n \cdot n )} = 2^{log(|Q|) + n\cdot log(|\Sigma|) + log(n)}$, which is exponential in $|w| = n$ as $|Q|$ and $|\Sigma|$ are constants. Note that the number of configurations takes into account in which state we're in, and at which tape-cell the head of the machine points.
- If the machine is not a decider, we cannot bound its runtime as it may not halt even when it uses bounded space. Note that in this case we can decide for sure if the machine does not halt as it must repeat a configuration given that it uses at most $n$ space.